# How can I read environment variables from a .env file into a terraform script?

Tags: terraform

I'm building a lambda function on aws with terraform. The syntax within the terraform script for uploading an env var is:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "name_of_function" {

  ...

  environment {
    variables = {
      foo     = "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have a `.env` file in my repo with a bunch of variables, e.g. `email='admin@example.com'`, and I'd like terraform to read (some of) them from that file and inject them into the space for env vars to be uploaded and available to the lambda function. How can this be done?

Comment: Can you use a [.tfvars file instead](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#variable-definitions-tfvars-files) and just treat them as standard terraform variables?  The basic syntax is still key/value pairs etc

Comment: I suppose, but then I have to maintain two files (and two templates) in my repo: .env and .tfvars :(

Comment: This question got closed for trivial-wording reasons (IMO). I have a solution if/when it's voted for reopening.

Comment: Hey @Magnus, did you find any better solution than what I posted?

Comment: @Jimbo OK -- done.  .

Answer (score 36):

This is a pure TerraForm-only solution that parses the `.env` file into a native TerraForm map.

```
output "foo" {
  value = { for tuple in regexall("(.*?)=(.*)", file("/path/to/.env")) : tuple[0] => tuple[1] }
}
```

I have defined it as an output to do quick tests via CLI but you can always define it as a local or directly on an argument.

Edited to allow env variables to contain `=`

Comment: I really like this, firstly because it's terraform native, and secondly because it's 'add and forget'. Nice solution.

Comment: If, like ours, your `.env` values sometimes contain `=` characters (e.g. base64 encoded values), you may want the first match to be non-greedy, as in: `...regexall("(.*?)=(.*)", ...`

Answer (score 17):

Based on @Uizz Underweasel response, I just add the sensitive function for security purposes:

**Definition** in variables.tf - **more** secure

```
locals {
  envs = { for tuple in regexall("(.*)=(.*)", file(".env")) : tuple[0] => sensitive(tuple[1]) }
}
```

**Definition** in variables.tf - **less** secure

```
locals {
  envs = { for tuple in regexall("(.*)=(.*)", file(".env")) : tuple[0] => tuple[1] }
}
```

An example of **.env**

```
HOST=127.0.0.1
USER=my_user
PASSWORD=pass123
```

**The usage**

```
output "envs" {
  value = local.envs["HOST"]
  sensitive = true # this is required if the sensitive function was used when loading .env file (more secure way)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this code snippet  here is an extended version of the regex to match quoted variables and strip whitespaces: `{for tuple in regexall((?m:^\\s*([^#\\s]\\S*)\\s*=\\s*[\"']?(.*[^\"'\\s])[\"']?\\s*$), file.env")) : tuple[0] => sensitive(tuple[1])}` (correctly extracts `  foo =  'hello'` and `bar="world"  ` but also `test  = 'mismatch"` and NOT `mystring = '"double quotes"'`)

It's a shame Terraform uses RE2, thus it is not possible to match a previously captured group to make sure the quotes match `^\s*([^#]\S*)\s*=\s*(["']?)(.*)\2$` which would extract `'"xx"'` -> `"xx"`

Comment: Will it look for .env file in the root? How it knows where is .env file?

Comment: Yep, but you can ensure the root path using the `"${path.module}/.env"`.

Comment: Doesn't work on this file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver/master/mailserver.env

Answer (score 15):

My solution for now involves 3 steps.

1. Place your variables in a .env file like so:

```
export TF_VAR_FOO=bar
```

Yes, it's slightly annoying that you HAVE TO prefix your vars with `TF_VAR_`, but I've learned to live with it (at least it makes it clear in your .env what vars will be used by terraform, and which will not.)

2. In your TF script, you have to declare any such variable without the `TF_VAR_` prefix. E.g.

```
variable "FOO" {
  description = "Optionally say something about this variable"
}
```

3. Before you run terraform, you need to source your .env file (`. .env`) so that any such variable is available to processes you want to launch in your present shell environment (viz. terraform here). Adding this step doesn't bother me since I always operate my repo with bash scripts anyway.

Note: I put in a request for a better way to handle .env files [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23906) though I'm actually now quite happy with things as is (it was just poorly described in the official documentation how TF relates to .env files IMO).

Comment: Just noting that "export TF_FOO" didnt work for me, but "export TF_VAR_FOO" did.

Comment: @Amir Agh -- that was a silly/annoying mistake. I obviously wrote that up sloppily. Indeed, all of the vars  in my .env files are prefixed TF_VAR_. I've now corrected the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Building on top of the great advice from @joe-jacobs, to avoid having to prepend to all variables with the `TF_VAR_` prefix, encapsulate the call to the `terraform` command with the excellent `https://github.com/cloudposse/tfenv` utility.

This means you can leave the vars defined as `FOO=bar` in the `.env file`, useful to re-use them for other purposes.

Then run a command like:

```
dotenv run tfenv terraform plan
```

Terraform will be able to find an env variable `TF_VAR_FOO` set to `bar`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `terraform.tfvars` or `.auto.tfvars` file. The second one is probably more alike the .env, because it's hidden too.

Not exactly bash `.env` format, but something very similar.

For example:

- `.env`

  ```bash
  var1=1
  var2="two"
  ```
- `.auto.tfvars`

  ```bash
  var1 = 1
  var2 = "two"
  ```

Also you can use json format. Personally, i've never done it, but it's possible.

It's described in the [official docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#variable-definitions-tfvars-files):

> Terraform also automatically loads a number of variable definitions files if they are present:
>
> - Files named exactly `terraform.tfvars` or `terraform.tfvars.json`.
> - Any files with names ending in `.auto.tfvars` or `.auto.tfvars.json`.

You still have to [declare](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#declaring-an-input-variable) variables though:

```
variable "var1" {
    type = number
}
variable "var2" {
    type = string
}
```

Answer (score 2):

More compact version with small touches, inspired by @fábio-filho and @Uizz Underweasel and [cedricbastin's reply on the GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23906#issuecomment-1413973319).

```
locals {
  dot_env_file_path = ".env"
  dot_env_regex     = "(?m:^\\s*([^#\\s]\\S*)\\s*=\\s*[\"']?(.*[^\"'\\s])[\"']?\\s*$)"
  dot_env           = { for tuple in regexall(local.dot_env_regex, file(local.dot_env_file_path)) : tuple[0] => sensitive(tuple[1]) }
  foo               = local.dot_env["FOO"]
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work on this file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver/master/mailserver.env

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a simple PHP script to read the env file in, parse it how I wanted (`explode()`, remove lines with '#', no other vars etc then `implode()` again), and just eval that in my makefile first. Looks like this:

```
provision:
    @eval $(php ./scripts/terraform-env-vars.php); \
    terraform init ./deployment/terraform; \
    terraform apply -auto-approve ./deployment/terraform/
```

---

Unfortunately terraform had the ridiculous idea that [all environmental variables must be prefixed with `TF_VAR_`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html#tf_var_name).

I solved this with a combination of `grep` and `sed`, with the idea that I would regex replace all environment variables with the required prefix.

Firstly you need to declare an [input variable](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#declaring-an-input-variable) with the same name as the environment variable in your .tf file:

```
variable "MY_ENV_VAR" {
  type = string
}
```

Then, before the terraform command, use the following:

`export $(shell sed -E 's/(.*)/TF_VAR_\1/' my.env | grep -v "#" | grep -v "TF_VAR_$"); terraform apply`

What this does:

- Uses `sed` to grab each line in a capture group with `(.*)`, then in the replacement prefixes `TF_VAR` with the first capture group (`\1`)
- Uses grep to remove all lines that have a comment on (anything with a `#`).
- Uses grep to remove all lines that only have `TF_VAR`.

Unfortunately this also has a bunch of other environmental variables created with the prefix `TF_VAR` and I'm not sure why, but this is at least a start to using `.env` files with terraform.

Answer (score 0):

I like python, and I don't like polluting my environmental variables, i used a python3 virtual environment and the `python-dotenv[cli]` package.  I know there's a dotenv in other languages, those may work also.

Here's what I did...

Looks something like this on my Mac

## set up your virtual environment, activate it, install packages

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install "python-dotenv[cli]"
```

## Put your environment variables into a `.env` file in the local directory

```
foo1 = "bar1"
foo2 = "bar2"
```

## Then when you run terraform, use the dotenv cli prefix

`dotenv run terraform plan`

## When you're done with your virtual environment

`deactivate`

## To start again at a later date, from your TF directory

`source venv/bin/activate`

This allows me to load up environment variables when i run other TF without storing them.

Answer (score 0):

Paul B has the best answer, it works with Env vars that are base64 encoded (has == at end)

```
envs = { for tuple in regexall("(.*?)=(.*)", trimspace(file("./.env"))) : tuple[0] => sensitive(tuple[1]) }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34705871)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
locals {
  environment_variables_lines = [for line in split("\n", file("${path.module}/mailserver.env")) : trimspace(line)]
  environment_variable_regex  = "^(\\w*)=(.+)$"
  environment_variables       = flatten([
    for line in local.environment_variables_lines :
    [for tuple in regexall(local.environment_variable_regex, line) : { name : tuple[0], value : tuple[1] }]
  ])
}
```

Tested on this file here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver/master/mailserver.env.